# how to cancel/hide the Incomming call intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

Friends

I wanted to know is there any way i can check for incoming call in android?

I also want to know if there is any way to cancel the Intent to show the incoming call?

If really we can cancel the Intent of showing incoming call then will the caller get ringing or get busy tone?

**UPDATED:**
May be i can not cancel the call but is there any way i can hide the incoming calling intent to be displayed to the user screen?

Please friends Guide me for these issues.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

You can detect incoming and outgoing calls.Check this [link](http://www.krvarma.com/posts/android/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/) -

But I'm afraid you cannot cancel an incoming call using the standard API available mainly due to security reasons.

Comment: then may be i can not cancel the call but is there any way i can hide the incoming calling intent to be displayed to the user screen?

Comment: cmon you can cancel commming calls, so how pebble watch which is communicationg with android, can cancel ??